# SSAS project error while executing CUBE manually

Tags: sql-server, runtime-error, ssas, business-intelligence

I am trying to execute CUBE manually from `VisualStudio`. But getting an error/warning at last. Actually I am new to SSAS Project. So could not understand the last message popup whether it successfully ran or not!

Could anyone please guide me for below Snapshot!

[image]

Why ① is looking like errors but ② is showing it as "*Process succeeded*". Is there any problem in my CUBE or its just because of the warning? may I need to consider it as any serious issue?

***Edited***: I have updated the Image as my Error messages counts reduced and even column name also changed without doing anything on the CUBE.

Comment: I guess they are warnings. 
But, you should be able to extend the error message clicking on the "+".
Deppending on the issue and your knowledge about the architecture of your cube, you may decide if you 'ignore' those or not.
Just by curiosity, can we get a screenshot about the extended error ?

Comment: @NickNick: Thank you for the Comment. I have updated the question with Warning messages. Please ask in case of Error messages are not readable!

Comment: Ok, I guess you have/you want a link between your measure group DC_something and the dimension "Cal Ym". So you should have a link between the column 'Cal_YM' in the table dbo_something and the table used to create the dimension CalYM.
If I were you... first, I would check, in the "dimension usage" (in visual studio), if the link between measure group and dimension is correct. Second, why the attribute you're using from the dimension side doesn't reference some values you have in the measure group (ex: 201809).
When you process the cube, is it a "full process" ?

Comment: sorry, looking on your screenshot, I have my answer about the process "full process" or not... Maybe that a solution is to reprocess the dimension too ... in order to update it for the new values you can find inside

Comment: @NickNick: Thanks a lot for your support and i really appreciate. Today I have rerun the CUBE and all errors are gone except last one, which i have updated in image. Recent errors count was '3040732'(all data) and not it's only '1'. But column name has been changed. Recent error was about 'CalYM' not it is changed to another one as 'BU_CODE'. Is there any clue on this?

Comment: @NickNick: I tried to follow your suggested steps on new error. And i found correct relationship between them. But if you notice in new snapshot, That value of field is EMPTY. Is there anything because of this? Also I have confirmed that NULL/BLANK does not exist in BU_CODE master table. could you please guide on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between NULL/BLANK and the value '' (which is an empty string). It looks like you have an empty string in the column BU_CODE in your measure group table and no key value '' (empty string) in your dimension table. Maybe I'm wrong but I sugggest you modify the value in your measure group table (change the '' by the correct value if the empty string is not) or you have to add this possible value in a new row of your dimension

Comment: Thanks for the help!! I have changed the value and now its working like a charm!